# regex — matching without trailing characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to match the following (these are all seperate strings):

```
'Los Angeles, CA'
'New York, NY'
'Williamsburg, Brooklyn, NY'
```

from the following strings:

```
'Los Angeles, CA 90001, USA'
'New York, NY 10017, USA'
'Williamsburg, Brooklyn, NY, USA'
```

I am using JavaScript. So far I have:

```
var re = /.+[A-Z]{2}( |,)/,
    location = '',  // Address string here
    substring = location.match(re)[0];  // Returns something like Williamsburg, Brooklyn, NY,
```

While this regex will match the string examples above, I am left with a trailing whitespace or a comma depending on the string. I can `slice()` the trailing character, but I was curious if this can be done within the regex itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the capturing group `( )` which matches up to the space character or comma without making either of them part of the match.

```
var re = /.+[A-Z]{2}(?= |,)/
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/dM1rR7)

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use the word boundary `.+\b[A-Z]{2}\b`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate ways :

```
substring = location.split(/([A-Z]{2})/, 2).join('');
substring = location.slice(0, location.search(/[A-Z]{2}/) + 2);
```